# How do I edit the HTML properties of an element by using document.queryselector()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am following a JavaScript course and I was wondering why this code is not working:

```
        document.querySelector('.message').style.width ='30rem';
        document.querySelector('.message').style.transition='0.3s';
```

This method works if I select HTML elements but does not work with classes. To fix the problem I thought it'd be useful if I edited the element's properties by adding the style property directly into the element like this:

```
<div class="message" style:"width=30rem; transition=0.3s;" > </div>
```

Comment: Class is not supposed to have a dot in html. Should be `<div class="message"></div>`. `class` CSS selector is `.`, `id` CSS selector is `#`.

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77340342/how-do-i-edit-the-html-properties-of-an-element-by-using-document-queryselector#comment136345174_77340342) If you fix that, and the code you've shown runs when the element exists, the code should work.

Comment: *"This method works if I select HTML elements but does not work with classes."* If you're asking how to do that for **multiple** matching elements, loop through the results of `querySelectorAll`. `querySelector` only returns the *first* matching element. More details about doing that in [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method).

Comment: Another typo: in CSS you declare the value of a property using `:` not `=` so your `style` attribute should be `style="width:30rem; transition:0.3s;"`

Comment: And... to be pedantic, `.message` is a valid value for the `class` attribute, you'd target it with the selector`".\\.message"` in JS or `.\.message` in CSS, which is super not practical at all, but... it's allowed.

Comment: Hello guys thank you for your answers! I actually did not type the class wrong (I didn’t put the dot in the HTML code) in the actual code, I did it here because I typed the question quickly .  You have all been kind I will now try to use  document.querySelectorAll();

Answer (score 1):

```
hope this can help, you have to correct class=".message" to class="message"

<div class="message">Some content</div>

<script>
    const customDiv = document.querySelector(".message");
    customDiv.style.cssText = 'width: 30rem; transition: width 0.3s;';
</script>
```

Comment: I will try it! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting each style property individually, combine them into one string and then apply them using the `cssText` property.

```js
document.querySelector('.message').style.cssText = 'border-radius:10px; width: 30rem; transition:0.3s;';
```

```html
<div class="message"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. you just need to fix the naming of your class

```
<div class=".message" style="width=30rem; transition=0.3s;" > </div>
```

this doesn't work since you have a dot in your HTML

the below code should work perfectly fine.

```
<div class="message" style="width=30rem; transition=0.3s;" > </div>
```

Comment: It was my bad while typing the question 